# Web Api routing trouble

Tags: c#, routes, asp.net-web-api

I have an self hosted Web API project, so I had to use [Yao's blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yaohuang1/archive/2012/12/20/making-asp-net-web-api-help-page-work-on-self-hosted-services.aspx) to make help page work. Next, I've had to secure some of my methods from unauthorized use. I've implemented [this idea](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/630986/Cross-Platform-Authentication-With-ASP-NET-Web-API#_rating).

Now the fun part. I have 3 routes:

`/help` which leads to Help Page,

`/authentication/authenticate` is used to call authentication method and it expects user credentials and returns security token in case of success

and `/transaction/{action}/{id}` this route needs to be secured from unauthorized use.

So basically, I need to make all routes, where controller = transaction, to be processed by `TokenInspector`.

**1. Scenario:** if I have routing configuration like this:

```
_config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "AuthenticatedOnly",
            routeTemplate: "transaction/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new {controller = "Transaction", action="GetNewTaskId", id=RouteParameter.Optional},
            constraints: null,
            handler: tokenInspector
            );

        _config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "Default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller="Help", action="Index", id = RouteParameter.Optional}
            );
```

Everything works fine, except Help page shows only `POST Authentication/Authenticate`
entry

**2. Scenario:** if I change routing config to:

```
_config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "AuthenticatedOnly",
            routeTemplate: "transaction/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new {},
            constraints: null,
            handler: tokenInspector
            );

        _config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "Default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller="Help", action="Index", id = RouteParameter.Optional}
            );
```

Help page works fine and shows all the methods, but `/transaction` is not secured anymore and is working without token.

**3. Scenario:**

```
_config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "AuthenticatedOnly",
                routeTemplate: "transaction/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new {id=RouteParameter.Optional},
                constraints: null,
                handler: tokenInspector
                );

            _config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                "Default",
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller="Help", action="Index", id = RouteParameter.Optional}
                );
```

Works both authentication and help page, but when I make request like `/Transaction/GetNewTaskId` with valid Token in it's header, I get 404.

**Update**
Could anyone explain, how help page generation depends on registered routes? Is there any way to tweak it and enforce `ApiExplorer` to print out controller contained stuff?

**Update 2**
After some more struggling and investigating, I found a solution, which matches my goal - to keep documentation as well as security pattern.
I've implemented a custom message handler (basically, I used my TokenInspector, but added url filtering to it's logic).

So, I have single route now:

```
_config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "Default",
                routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Help", action = "Index", id=RouteParameter.Optional }
                );
```

and this is how I launch the server:

```
_config = new ExtendedHttpSelfHostConfiguration(ServiceAddress);
            TokenInspector tokenInspector = new TokenInspector() { InnerHandler = new HttpRoutingDispatcher(_config) };
            _server = new HttpSelfHostServer(_config, tokenInspector);
            ConfigureHost(_config);
            _server.OpenAsync();
```

Probably, the question as it was, could not be answered in this way, but anyway, thank you all for your effort!

Regards, insomnium_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//This is for your public controllers
//this route will ONLY catch requests for Help and Authentication controllers only
//you will need to include any new public controller that uses the route pattern
_config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Public",
    routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    constraints: new  { controller = @"^(Help|Authentication)$" },
    defaults: new { controller="Help", action="Index", id = RouteParameter.Optional}
);


//Everything that is not Help or Authentication will use this route, which will check for the valid token you mention
//This route is defaulting to /Transaction/GetNewTaskId    
_config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
     name: "AuthenticatedOnly",
     routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
     defaults: new { controller = "Transaction", action="GetNewTaskId", id=RouteParameter.Optional},
     handler: tokenInspector
);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! I tried your suggested variant, but it leads to 2. Scenario behaviour.

Comment: Are Help and Authenticatatioon the only public controllers you have?

Comment: All controllers are marked as `public`, methods located Help and Authentication should be available for any user, requests for Transaction controller should be checked if they contain valid token.

Comment: Edited my answer above. Please take into account that I'm actually typing code in this editor, so bear with me if there is any typo.

Comment: Actually, you can remove the id from the first route if Help or Authentication actions don't use it. It is optional, I know, but I tend to keep my routes as simple as possible and then modify them as needed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Now I get all my `Transaction` methods displayed on help page and secured with `TokenInspector`. The only thing I'm missing is `Authentication/Authenticate` entry oh help page. Could you explain, how the help page generation is depending on the routing?

Comment: The limitation is placed on HelpControllerBase which is only using the Default route for the help page. Any other controller that is not on the Default route will not be included in your help page.
Because you are specifying the tokenExplorer in the route, you CAN'T put a public and restricted controller in the same route; this is not flexible.
You can, however, populate the identity in the tokenExplorer, and then use the [Authorize] attribute on both your controllers and/or your actiions.
This is the built in authorization mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Use this approach for more flexible method access management

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
   name: "PublicMethods",
   routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
   constraints: new {action = @"^(public)-(.)*$"},
   defaults: new {controller = "Account"}
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
   name: "PublicControllers",
   routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
   constraints: new {controller = @"^(Environment|Account)$"},
   defaults: new {controller = "Account"}
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
   name: "AuthorizedUsersOnly",
   routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
   defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
   constraints: null,
   handler: tokenInspector
);
```

So I have few open for each user controllers and if it's necessary I make some methods accessible for not authorized users by adding 'public' prefix to action name